exporting cryptomattes using HALF FLOAT multilayer EXR - not working
I have no problem when exporting light passes (render layer) as multilayer EXR using Half Float. But Half Float doesn't work when exporting cryptomattes. I have to use Full Float to make it work. I'm using blender 4.1.1
Is this normal ? or blender's bug ?
